# Display csv file horizontally

Tags: python, csv

**InputfilesListInplane** is the **file directory** that i am reading data from, I am allow to choose multiple data and obtain the result from their respective folder.
[image]

My program will extract FieldIP and SignalIP every time 1 data is extracted in. It will look something like this

```
Extracted FieldIP and SignalIP (SignalIP contains more data than FieldIP)
FieldIP = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16...]
SignalIP = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,12,20,40...]
```

Code i tried but data just keep stacking vertically.

```
newfile = "C:/VSMPlots/TabulatedStatsVSM.csv"
with open(newfile, "wb") as csvfile:
    for file_path_IP in InputfilesListInplane: 
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
        writer.writerow(["FieldIP", "SignalIP"])
        writer.writerow([" "])
        for field, signal in zip(FieldIP, signalIP):
            writer.writerow([field,signal])
        writer.writerow("")
```

My Code will present in this format

[image]

How can i make it into this format

[image]

Comment: You'll need to open all the input files at the same time. Read one row from each file and combine them together when you write to your output file.

Comment: Agreed.  And overall_list.extend(sublist) is a good way to do it, where sublist is each row you need to combine in turn.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np

a = np.asarray([[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]])
np.savetxt("foo.csv", a, delimiter=",")
```

Above code will give you:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

So basically, read all data from your files, arrange them in `a`.

```
import numpy as np

dat1 = np.genfromtxt('foo1', delimiter=',')
dat2 = np.genfromtxt('foo2', delimiter=',')

a = np.hstack((dat1, dat2))

np.savetxt("foo.csv", a, delimiter=",", fmt="%d")
```

Suppose:

```
foo1:             foo2:
1,2               3,4
1,2               3,4
1,2               3,4
```

The above code with give you:

```
1,2,3,4
1,2,3,4
1,2,3,4
```